# SNowflake - Syntax error: unexpected '<EOF>'. Query size limit?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, procedure, eof

I have a procedure and I want to modify this. When I use this request:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE import_stage_sfr_ac_reeng_fixe_handicall_bordeaux(p_loading_mode VARCHAR)
RETURNS VARCHAR NOT NULL
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
BEGIN
 
    IF (:p_loading_mode ='incremental') THEN
        COPY INTO SFR_AC_REENG_FIXE_HANDICALL_BORDEAUX (
            V_NUM_COMMANDE_MIG,
            V_SITE_CMD,
            V_ACTIVITE_EZY,
            V_TYPE_AC,
            D_JOUR_CMD,
            D_JOUR_PANIER,
            V_SEMAINE_CMD,
            V_MOIS_CMD,
            V_LOGIN_CC_CMD,
            V_NUM_CONTRAT,
 
            V_TYPE_ACTE,
            B_MIG,
            V_COURANT_PTA_MIG,
            V_LIBL_COURANT_PTA_MIG,
            V_FUTUR_PTA_MIG,
            V_LIBL_FUTUR_PTA_MIG,
            V_LIBL_FUTUR_PTA_MIG_COURT,
            B_REMISE,
            V_LIBL_REMISE,
            N_MT_REMISE_M_TTC,
 
            B_USAGE,
            V_LIBL_USAGE,
            V_NOM,
            V_PRENOM,
            N_FACIAL_AVANT,
            N_FACIAL_APRES,
            N_REMISE_AVANT,
            N_REMISE_APRES,
            N_MOUVEMENT_VALEUR,
            V_CODE_CAMPAGNE,
            
            B_FLAG_HBD,
            V_CODE_CAMPAGNE,
            V_CODE_LOT,
            V_RAC,
            
            V_TECH_NOM_FICHIER,
            V_TECH_STATUT_TRAITEMENT,
            V_TECH_NOM_TRAITEMENT,
            TS_TECH_DEBUT_TRAITEMENT
        ) FROM ( 
        SELECT
            $12,
            $1,
            $2,
            $3,
            TO_DATE($4, 'YYYY-MM-DD'),
            TO_DATE($5, 'YYYY-MM-DD'),
            $6,
            $7,
            $8,
            $9,
 
            $10,
            CAST($11 AS BOOLEAN),
            $13,
            $14,
            $15,
            $16,
            $17,
            CAST($18 AS BOOLEAN),
            $19,
            CAST($20 AS NUMBER(10, 0)),
            
            CAST($21 AS BOOLEAN),
            $22,
            $23,
            $24,
            CAST(REPLACE($25, ',', '.') AS NUMBER(6, 3)),
            CAST(REPLACE($26, ',', '.') AS NUMBER(6, 3)),
            CAST(REPLACE($27, ',', '.') AS NUMBER(4, 2)),
            CAST(REPLACE($28, ',', '.') AS NUMBER(4, 2)),
            CAST(REPLACE($29, ',', '.') AS NUMBER(6, 3)),
            $30,
 
            TO_BOOLEAN($31),
            $32,
            $33,
            $34,
            
            METADATA$FILENAME,
            'I',
            'INGEST MODE : '|| :p_loading_mode,
            current_timestamp(0)
        FROM  @ES_SFR )
        FILE_FORMAT  = ( FORMAT_NAME  = FF_INGEST_CSV_SFR)
        PATTERN  =  '.*incremental.*ac_reeng_fixe_handicall_bordeaux.*\.csv';
    END IF;
```

It work. But if I add just a column, I have the message `Syntax error: unexpected '<EOF>'.` no matter the column.

*Example:*

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE import_stage_sfr_ac_reeng_fixe_handicall_bordeaux(p_loading_mode VARCHAR)
RETURNS VARCHAR NOT NULL
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
BEGIN
 
    IF (:p_loading_mode ='incremental') THEN
        COPY INTO SFR_AC_REENG_FIXE_HANDICALL_BORDEAUX (
            V_NUM_COMMANDE_MIG,
            V_SITE_CMD,
            V_ACTIVITE_EZY,
            V_TYPE_AC,
            D_JOUR_CMD,
            D_JOUR_PANIER,
            V_SEMAINE_CMD,
            V_MOIS_CMD,
            V_LOGIN_CC_CMD,
            V_NUM_CONTRAT,
 
            V_TYPE_ACTE,
            B_MIG,
            V_COURANT_PTA_MIG,
            V_LIBL_COURANT_PTA_MIG,
            V_FUTUR_PTA_MIG,
            V_LIBL_FUTUR_PTA_MIG,
            V_LIBL_FUTUR_PTA_MIG_COURT,
            B_REMISE,
            V_LIBL_REMISE,
            N_MT_REMISE_M_TTC,
 
            B_USAGE,
            V_LIBL_USAGE,
            V_NOM,
            V_PRENOM,
            N_FACIAL_AVANT,
            N_FACIAL_APRES,
            N_REMISE_AVANT,
            N_REMISE_APRES,
            N_MOUVEMENT_VALEUR,
            V_CODE_CAMPAGNE,
            
            B_FLAG_HBD,
            V_CODE_CAMPAGNE,
            V_CODE_LOT,
            V_RAC,
            V_PROMO_TR,
            
            V_TECH_NOM_FICHIER,
            V_TECH_STATUT_TRAITEMENT,
            V_TECH_NOM_TRAITEMENT,
            TS_TECH_DEBUT_TRAITEMENT
        ) FROM ( 
        SELECT
            $12,
            $1,
            $2,
            $3,
            TO_DATE($4, 'YYYY-MM-DD'),
            TO_DATE($5, 'YYYY-MM-DD'),
            $6,
            $7,
            $8,
            $9,
 
            $10,
            CAST($11 AS BOOLEAN),
            $13,
            $14,
            $15,
            $16,
            $17,
            CAST($18 AS BOOLEAN),
            $19,
            CAST($20 AS NUMBER(10, 0)),
            
            CAST($21 AS BOOLEAN),
            $22,
            $23,
            $24,
            CAST(REPLACE($25, ',', '.') AS NUMBER(6, 3)),
            CAST(REPLACE($26, ',', '.') AS NUMBER(6, 3)),
            CAST(REPLACE($27, ',', '.') AS NUMBER(4, 2)),
            CAST(REPLACE($28, ',', '.') AS NUMBER(4, 2)),
            CAST(REPLACE($29, ',', '.') AS NUMBER(6, 3)),
            $30,
 
            TO_BOOLEAN($31),
            $32,
            $33,
            $34,
            $35,
            
            METADATA$FILENAME,
            'I',
            'INGEST MODE : '|| :p_loading_mode,
            current_timestamp(0)
        FROM  @ES_SFR )
        FILE_FORMAT  = ( FORMAT_NAME  = FF_INGEST_CSV_SFR)
        PATTERN  =  '.*incremental.*ac_reeng_fixe_handicall_bordeaux.*\.csv';
    END IF;
```

I search since this morning, I was able to add more column by deleting the comments. I therefore really wonder if this is not a limitation of the number of characters in the procedure. Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: are you sure that the first one works?

Comment: The first one return : `Function IMPORT_STAGE_SFR_AC_REENG_FIXE_HANDICALL_BORDEAUX successfully created`. If I replace by $35 the $34 column I have the same message. If I try to add a column, I have the error. If I execute the request alone, without procedure, it works.

Comment: [Using String Constant Delimiters Around a Block in a Stored Procedure](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/running-examples#using-string-constant-delimiters-around-a-block-in-a-stored-procedure)

Comment: Can you try adding double dollar signs ```$$``` before the first ```BEGIN``` and after the last ```END```and check if it works?  as shown [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/blocks#using-a-block-in-a-stored-procedure)

Comment: I have test and import and it works ! Thanks you ! I lost syntax highlighting but it's OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the issue you need to add the `$$` sings to quote the code block.

Example:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE import_stage_sfr_ac_reeng_fixe_handicall_bordeaux(p_loading_mode VARCHAR)
RETURNS VARCHAR NOT NULL
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
$$
BEGIN
--your code the scripting block
END
$$;
```

[Doc reference.](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/running-examples#using-string-constant-delimiters-around-a-block-in-a-stored-procedure)